# My Ubuntu is 13.10, how to do a clean install of 16.04.2 LTS

Tags: system-installation, upgrade

My present Ubuntu is 13.10 and it always wants to update to the latest version, but it cannot.

I have made a USB drive and DVD of Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS amd64 using Rufus.

I really want to have a clean install and do not need any of the data on the computer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do a clean install then boot from the USB and install the new version of Ubuntu, when you get the partition/ drive screen I believe it should format them or you can tell it to format them (depends on what options you select).

Since you want a clean install it would be just like installing it over again.